# How to share drive space from vmware server 2 host to a guest?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-server, network-share

In the vmware tools in the guest there is an option to access shares from the host.

What is the way to create such shares on a vmware 2 host? I did not find where in infrastructure web access. I also went through the vmware server 2 user's guide but did not see it mentioned. Can you help?

This is an ubuntu 64 bit server 8.04 LTS host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not present on Vmware server, but their tools package includes the features that will work on the workstation prodcuts..  The shared folders feature doesn't really make much sense there compared to their workstation products.  Just setup NFS/samba or something else on your server and access it that way.